# WooCommerce page css file

Tags: css, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, css-selectors

I'm attempting to rearrange the layout for my WooCommerce pages, specifically the individual product page. But I can't find where the CSS code is. I'm looking for:

```
class="woocommerce-tabs wc-tabs-wrapper"
```

The css file for `woocommerce-tabs wc-tabs-wrapper`.

Comment: Could you provide a link to your website please? editing your question…

Comment: I do it local but wordpress\wp-content\plugins\woocommerce\templates\single-product\tabs the class is in tabs.php and i just want to change the css file of it

Comment: Never override woocommerce files located in plugin folder!!! (see my answer).

Answer (score 3):

The woocommerce CSS files are located in the woocommerce plugin folder:

- woocommerce > assets > css > woocommerce.css
- woocommerce > assets > css > woocommerce-layout.css

**Overriding WooCommerce CSS rules:**
But if you want to override this rules is better just copy the rules you want to change in your `style.css` file located inside your active child theme or theme, adding `!important` attribute to these overriding rules if needed.
Also in some themes they customize this rules. So in that case, you will need to find that rules on css files of your parent active theme…

**Editing woocommerce templates files**: You need to copy this `templates` folder located inside woocommerce plugin to your active child theme or theme folder, and rename-it `woocommerce`:

[Overriding Templates via a Theme](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/)

**Note:** In some Premium themes, this `woocommerce` folder already exist, because they have already customized this templates…

Comment: As an alternative to adding `!important` everywhere, you can enqueue a stylesheet with a higher/later priority so that it will come *after* the woocommerce stylesheets.

Comment: @helgatheviking Yes that is right, I totally agree. But this is just a bit more complicated thing for a beginners. Thanks :)